# Parsing XML file using XMLDocument and moving causes exception

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I am trying to read an XML file and export the data to DB. I use XMLDocument to read the contents. After exporting the content i am moving the file to a archive location. To avoid name conflicts before moving i am appending the filename with timestamp. The problem is when i repeatedly export the same xml file at one point in time i am getting an exception "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another program".

My guess is the xml document loaded in memory is not freed yet. Is there any way to avoid this issue?

**UPDATE**

I tried all the code related to reading and exporting the xml file. My code now has only these lines

```
fName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss") + fileName;
fName = destinationPath + "\\" + fName;

File.Move(sourcePath, fName);
```

now when i run it first time it works fine. Then i wait for 2 seconds and then try to export it again now it is throwing me an exception

Answer (score 0):

same xml in one point of time cannot be - at least milliseconds must be different. but i think you will get a lot of files. may be you need change the way